# Only jquery 3.2.1 or jquery mobile 1.4.5 is being loaded, why?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Only jquery or jquery mobile is loading from the `head` in my html file.

If I change the order of them in the `head` it switches between which one is being loaded. Could it be a compatibility issue?

```js
<head>
    
    <title>blablabla</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="resources/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"</script> 
    <script src="resources/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"</script>
    

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="js/client.js"></script> 
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>


</head>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are both a loading order issue and a compatibility version issue.

- Loading order:

.This is the correct loading order for jQuery and JQM:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('mobileinit', function() {
      // JQM Initialization options
    });
  </script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

- Version compatibility (source: [jQuery Mobile homepage: (http://jquerymobile.com/)):

> JQM Version 1.4.5 is compatible with jQuery 1.8 - 1.11 / 2.1